# mod_rewrite is enabled, but not working

Tags: apache2, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get a PHP routing library set up. They give this example for a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I couldn't get this to work, so I tried enabling mod_rewrite, but it says "Module rewrite already enabled".

Why is it not working properly? Thanks!
I'm running Ubuntu Precise 12.04, and apache2.2.22. (Checked for any updates)

EDIT: A couple more details, it's a PuPHPet vagrant build, rewrite should be enabled.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to allow the overwrite.

```
<Directory "/path/to/document/root/">
  AllowOverride All

</Directory>
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily permissive.  Only `AllowOverride` is necessary for the configuration in question.  `Allow from All` has nothing to do with the question and may not be appropriate for @randomdev's environment.

Answer (score 21):

First of all, **set your httpd configuration** to this (the path may differ with one another.  In my ubuntu it's placed at /etc/apache2/sites-available/default):

```
DocumentRoot /var/www

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

After that, you should **enable mod_rewrite** with this command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

The last one, **restart your apache** service:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

To ensure that, you can check it again from **phpinfo** in **Configuration > apache2handler > Loaded Modules** there must be written `mod_rewrite` and it means mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Should this be in a virtual host element?

Comment: You can see some example in [Apache Virtual Host Example](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

Answer (score 5):

I had the similar problem, but the other answers did not helped me. This line at the begining of `.htaccess` solved my problem:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

Comment: This did not help me either. Tried this and everything else and still got 404, a2enmod says module already enabled and I also have restarted my whole server a few times.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I didn't have `RewriteEngine on` set early on in the file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName &URL&
        ServerAlias *.&URL&

        ServerAdmin &EMAIL_ADDRESS&

        DocumentRoot            /var/www/&URL&/public

        RewriteEngine on

        # LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
        # Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
        # "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
        LogLevel                debug

        ErrorLog                /var/www/&URL&/storage/logs/apache2_error.log
        TransferLog             /var/www/&URL&/storage/logs/apache2_transfer.log

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|html|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>

        # <------------  Here I used to have `RewriteEngine on`

        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L,QSA]

</VirtualHost>
```

I dont know why but it helped when I placed `RewriteEngine on` higher up.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I moved one site from a different partition to the Apache's partition, but I had to create a symlink for the old location pointing this folder. The problem was that DocumentRoot was not updated, kept pointing to the old path, that is a link now.

**PS**: It is NOT a comercial website, only an intranet for "domestic" use.

So MOD_REWRITE stopped working because **DocumentRoot** was not poiting to the new folder path, but to the link end.

```
[ partition A (Apache) ] <-- Folder moved  <-- [ FOLDER partition B ]

[ partition A (Apache) ] --> Symbolic link --> [ (link) partition B ]
```

When I updated DocumentRoot with the real folder that now is in "A", it solved the problem.